# TTY Resolution in Xubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, resolution, xubuntu, grub, tty

I've exhausted my ability to search through Google for this, so I'm giving it a go here.

What I'm trying to do is increase the resolution (or decrease the font size) in the TTY terminals.  Xubuntu 9.10 uses GRUB2, and everywhere I can find directs me to edit the

```
/etc/default/grub
```

File in order to add `vga=XXX` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` value, and this simply doesn't work.  Out of endless fiddling with the file, nothing ever seems to change.

On my Netbook running an earlier version, I had success with this command

```
dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

But once again it yields no change.

Got any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for a way to do this for an Ubuntu 9.10 guest in VirtualBox, and got about halfway there.  In my VM, the console TTYs get the correct resolution if I boot into single-user mode, but not if I boot into GDM.

Grub2 replaces the *vga=XXX* kernel option with a ***gfxpayload*** option that can be set in */boot/grub/grub.cfg*.  Ubuntu's *update-grub* command automatically generates *grub.cfg* from variables in */etc/default/grub* and scripts in */etc/grub.d*, so the best place to add this option is in one of those two places.

These are the Grub2 options (in *grub.cfg* syntax) that affect the console resolution:

- ***gfxmode***: Sets the resolution of the Grub menu.
  eg: `set gfxmode=1280x800` (*no explicit bitdepth*)
  eg: `set gfxmode=1440x900x32` (*explicit bitdepth*)
- ***gfxpayload***: Sets the resolution Grub passes to the kernel.
  eg: `set gfxpayload=1024x720x16`
  eg: `set gfxpayload=keep` (*keeps resolution as set in **gfxmode***)

On my system, I added some scripting to the */etc/grub.d/00_header* to support a new *GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD* variable that's specified in */etc/grub/default*.  This isn't strictly necessary, and there are lots of ways to do it; see the examples on the Debian and Ubuntu forum links below.

Sources:

- [Grub2 graphical boot tips to set the desired VGA console mode](http://harrison3001.blogspot.com/2009/09/grub-2-graphical-boot-tips-to-set.html)
- [examples of tweaking */etc/grub.d/00_header*](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=41881#p258728) (forums.debian.net)
- [Grub2 bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=536453) requesting an */etc/default/grub* option to set ***gfxpayload***; indicates **GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX** is supported in Grub2 v1.98.  Ubuntu 9.10 currently uses v1.97.
- [Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8631840&postcount=6) on the same topic.  indicates some *vga=* modes work, others don't.

Comment: A +1 for you for such a comprehensive answer, but I've still yet to get this thing to change in any way.  Bigger, smaller, GRUB menu or the TTY itself. AGH!

Comment: @Zurahn: yeah, i played around with it some more after jotting up this answer, and my VMs aren't any closer to what i want to see.  one of the Ubuntu Forums links suggests replacing the *linux* and *initrd* commands with *linux16* and *initrd16* (and then using the older *vga=* syntax) but i haven't found any modes that that works properly with.  :(

Comment: I finally got a solution: reverting to legacy GRUB.  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1298932